# Animation of water in cylinder with jquery based on mySQL variables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css, animation

I need to create an animation of the water-level in a tank, based on MySQL Variables, which I get every 5 seconds from a database.

The value is from 1 to 100, and it means %, so the goal is, that depending on the % value the water moves smoothly up or down.

So far I have this:

***script to check every 5000ms the value from database :***

```
$(document).ready(function () {setInterval(function() {$.get("http://www.h2o-info.com/betapage/script_water_detail.php", function (result) {$('#water_detail').html(result);});}, 5000); });
```

***and show the result in a div:***

```
<div id="water_detail"></div>
```

***script_water_detail.php :***

```
<?php

// Connect to MySQL
$link = mysql_connect( 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx' );
if ( !$link ) {
  die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() );
}

// Select the data base
$db = mysql_select_db( 'xxx', $link );
if ( !$db ) {
  die ( 'Error selecting database \'xxx\' : ' . mysql_error() );
}
    $query = mysql_query("select V_00 from SensorLog where S_ID = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    {    

?>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#water_detailed").css({
height:'<?php echo round ($row['V_00'], 0); ?>px'})
});
</script>


<?php
if($row['V_00']<='0'){
print "<div class='water_fill_1'>";
echo round ($row['V_00'], 0);
"</div>";
}

elseif ($row['V_00']<='2'){
print "<div class='water_fill_5'>";
echo round ($row['V_00'], 0);
"</div>";

}else{
print "<div id='water_detailed'></div>";
}


} // End while loop

?>
```

***the css properties :***

```
 #water_detailed {
    background: #e2f4ff; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e2f4ff 0%, #a1dbff 47%, #00b0fc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e2f4ff), color-stop(47%,#a1dbff), color-stop(100%,#00b0fc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e2f4ff 0%,#a1dbff 47%,#00b0fc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e2f4ff 0%,#a1dbff 47%,#00b0fc 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e2f4ff 0%,#a1dbff 47%,#00b0fc 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e2f4ff 0%,#a1dbff 47%,#00b0fc 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e2f4ff', endColorstr='#00b0fc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    width: 280px;
    height:0;
    float:right;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    }

    #water_detail {
    width: 280px;
    margin: -275px 100px 0 0;
    float: right;
    }
```

So far I have the following result:

[Betalink](http://www.h2o-info.com/betapage/home/teilanlage-1/)

How you can see, it doesn't work properly, how I said first, it should on the first page load smoothly "fill" from bottom to top regarding the actual value and then change up or down, depending on the values of the database.

Perhaps someone has any suggestions.

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imho the easiest solution would be to have a white `div` and put a blue child `div` into it, which has it's `margin-top` value from your database percentage

(Plus the parent `div` has to have it's `overflow` set to `hidden`, not showing the hidden water part).

Have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7b8z/1/) to see it in action.

### Code

*HTML:*

```
<div id="water_detail">
    <div id="water_level"></div>
<div>
```

*CSS:*

```
#water_detail { height:200px; background:white; overflow:hidden; width:250px; }
#water_level  { height:200px; background:blue; margin-top:200px;/*initially*/ }
```

*Javascript:*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("http://www.h2o-info.com/betapage/script_water_detail.php", function (result) {
            //$('#water_detail').html(result);
            $('#water_level').animate({'margin-top' : (200-result*2)+'px'});
        });
    },5000); 
});
```

The `(200-result*2)` is only due to the div being "twice the height" of your max value (100% = 200px). Possibly a more "accurate" way would be to write: `div_width - (result/100 * div_width)`

(In this case a level of 0% results in `margin-top:200px`, 50% in `margin-top:100px`, etc.)

### How to make it look nicer

- Set a **static image** as the childs background, instead of just a single color
- Even better: Take an **animated gif** that moves the way water does

### Working Example

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7b8z/1/) for an example of a water level animation (with random water levels).

### Solution, Specific To OP

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("http://www.h2o-info.com/betapage/script_water_detail.php", function (result) {
            $('#water_level').animate( {'margin-top' : (200-result*2)+'px' } );
        });
    },2000); 
});
```

This gets the water level every 2 seconds! Change the last `2000` to what you prefer, it is just the interval (to apply the script) in milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how it should look like, I will try to implement it now in my project, hopefully it works.

Comment: As mentioned, you could even take an image (or animation) of water and set it as background for the child instead of just using blue. `background: url('water.gif') no-repeat top left;` for example.

Comment: Here an example with image: http://jsfiddle.net/R7b8z/4/ This additionally implements an offset, to always show at least a small part of the image, just to demonstrate that as well. If possible (in respect to resources) you could also try and set the interval for your database queries to something as low as 700ms, which would most likely look pretty fluent/nice with real-world data (not with the jumpy random values though ^^).

Comment: Ok, the animation works nice:http://www.h2o-info.com/betapage/home/teilanlage-1/ with random values, but:
- the animation is very fast, changing the value of duration doesnt take effect
- how can I achieve to get the values from $row of script_water_detail.php in the script, I saw, that you excluded //$.get("http://www.h2o-info.com/betapage/script_water_detail.php", function (result) {, but I don't get it :/

Comment: I just excluded it, because I was not able to get values from there to to the fiddle! You will have to comment out this line `var result = Math.rand...` and remove the comment from your `$.get("h2o-...` (as well as closing brackets of course), and it should already work. Or even better, if you just moved the whole `$('#water_level').animate(...` line to your other ajax call where you set the html value! (Just place it right after `$('#sensor1_val').html(result);` for example) ... btw, you could upvote/accept this answer if it solves your problem :-)

Comment: I guess I am to dumb for this:

$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function() {
$.get("http://www.h2o-info.com/betapage/script_water_detail.php", function (result){$('#water_level').animate( {'margin-top' : (200-result*2)+'px' } );});},5000,);});

Get values every 700ms:

$(document).ready(function () {setInterval(function() {$.get("http://www.h2o-info.com/betapage/script_water_detail.php", function (result) {$('#water_detail').html(result);
});}, 700); });

<div id="water_detail"><div id="water_level"></div></div>

I am totally confused, the php is the same like in my first post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58703/discussion-between-user3909146-and-levit).

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to make it appear that the water is filling up.
   Use a blue `<div>` which is under (ie: covered by) a grey `<div>`. For this example, lets set both <div> height to 100 px. Hence reducing the grey <div> height would uncover more of the blue <div>.
2. Next, parse the output from PHP and on success, run `$("#grey_div").animate( {"height": 100 - parseInt(result_from_php)} );`

Comment: Pretty much the same idea like my answer, but good idea to use the **height** of the child-div instead of **margin** with `overflow:hidden;` like I suggested! Makes it somewhat easier, but just note that in this case, you cannot simply replace the div with a water image (or gif-animation). Good use of `animate` too!

Comment: I tried to use .animate, but then animation gets repeated continously and I don't know why.

Furthermore the "water" is always animated from top to bottom, but the goal would be to have on the first page visit displayed the actual % value, then, if you stay on the page, the value get refreshed every 5000 ms and the graphic should slowly move up or down, depending on the value.

Comment: @user3909146: I added a working example with `animate` to the bottom of my answer, take a look!

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing so much inside script_water_detail.php.

You should just echo the % of water in this script using which you can animate the water level inside the jQuery function.

The animation shouldn't be the hard part, it is simply increasing the height of the #water_detailed div.

So basically, I think the problem will disappear once the structure is corrected.

Forgive me for not providing any code, but if you need anymore help, then I might code it and give you but I think it won't be needed.

Comment: Yes, I know, because I tried so far a lot of things and it makes me crazy.

First I have the div #water_detail, which I only need to update the values every 5000 ms via javascript and get the current value.

Then inside I have another div #water_detailed, which should visualize the value with animation, on the first page load the current % value and if you stay on the page change the graphic depending on the value smoothly up and down.